# I'm building a project "Tsp the numbers" and cannot understand why it does not run correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css

At the end of this code I get undefined instead of the print "Done!"

Here's my code:

```
const gContainer = document.querySelector(".container")
const gTable = document.querySelector('table')
const gNumbers = []
var chosenNum
var chosenLength;


onInit()

function onInit() {
    userChoice()
}

function playGame() {
    var counter = 0
    if (counter === gCells.length) {
        console.log('Done!')
    } else {
        const gCells = document.querySelectorAll('td')
        chosenNum = drawNum()
        console.log(`The chosen number is ${chosenNum}! Tap it!`)
        // gCells[idxOfEl].style.backgroundColor = 'yellow'
        const idxOfCell = gNumbers.indexOf(chosenNum)
        if (gCells[idxOfCell].style.backgroundColor === 'red') {
            counter++
        }
        gNumbers.splice(idxOfCell, 1)
    }
}

function cellClicked(cell) {
    const numInsideCell = parseInt(cell.innerText)
    // const timestamp = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
    if (numInsideCell === chosenNum) {
        console.log('Awesome!')
        cell.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        playGame();
    } else {
        console.log('You tapped the wrong number.')
    }
}


function drawNum() {
    const idxOfEl = Math.floor(Math.random() * (gNumbers.length))
    return gNumbers[idxOfEl]
}


function addNumbers(numOfCells) {
    var randNum = 0
    var counter = 0
    while (counter < numOfCells) {
        randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (50 - 1) + 1)
        if (!gNumbers.includes(randNum)) {
            gNumbers.push(randNum)
            counter++
        } else continue
    }
}

// ------------

function userChoice() {
    var strHTML = ''
    strHTML += `
    <h1 style="text-align:center;margin:30px">Tap the numbers!</h1>
    <p>Please choose how many cells would you like to have:</p>
    <ul>
    <li onclick="displayBoard(this)">16</li>
    <li onclick="displayBoard(this)">25</li>
    <li onclick="displayBoard(this)">36</li>
    </ul>`
    gContainer.innerHTML = strHTML
}

function displayBoard(numOfCells) {
    chosenLength = parseInt(numOfCells.innerText)
    gTable.style.display = 'table'
    var chosenLength = parseInt(numOfCells.innerText)
    addNumbers(chosenLength)
    var counter = 0
    var strHTML = ''
    strHTML += `<tbody>`
    for (var i = 0; i < Math.sqrt(chosenLength); i++) {
        strHTML += `<tr>`
        for (var j = 0; j < Math.sqrt(chosenLength); j++) {
            strHTML += `<td data-location="${i}${j}" onclick="cellClicked(this)">${gNumbers[counter]}</td>`
            counter++
        }
        strHTML += `</tr>`
    }
    strHTML += `</tbody>`
    gTable.innerHTML = strHTML
    playGame()
}
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Number tapping Game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        
    </div>
    <div class="table"><table></table></div>
    <script src="js/code.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Getting undefined at the last number instead of the print "Done!"
If you have any other improvements to suggest - I'd be glad to hear!

Comment: Please include your html so we can run and debug.

Comment: `if (counter === gCells.length) {`: `gCells` is not defined.

Comment: Changed it to be in the beginning of the function, it still returns unfedined instead of 'Done!'.

Comment: What have you done to debug it?

Comment: I tried to change and add some variables, asked many students that are also in the process of finding the solution to this problem and I tried to find a person who already created this specific game on youtube, and found no one :(

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint on the first line inside playGame and step through the code using the "Sources" part of your browser's developer tools.

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your title should be a clear, specific question (without salutations).

Comment: Are you using your browser devtools inspect facility to find exactly what is being done where?

Comment: Can you add Stack Snippets to the question?

Comment: Hey guys! It was already late in my country back then. I wanted to let you know that I solved it using your ideas, the problem was in a few conditions. I still am confused about the nodelist and what can and can't I do when checking for variables with it, but i'm glad I'm closer to completely understanding the topic thanks to you. Once again, thank you! Have a great day and happy codding!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are checking counter === gCells.length before initializing gCells inside the playGame function. Move the declaration of gCells outside of the if statement, and it should work correctly.

```js
const gContainer = document.querySelector(".container")
const gTable = document.querySelector('table')
const gNumbers = []
var chosenNum
var chosenLength;


onInit()

function onInit() {
    userChoice()
}

function playGame() {
const gCells = document.querySelectorAll('td')//move this here
    var counter = 0
    if (counter === gCells.length) {
        console.log('Done!')
    } else {
        
        chosenNum = drawNum()
        console.log(`The chosen number is ${chosenNum}! Tap it!`)
        // gCells[idxOfEl].style.backgroundColor = 'yellow'
        const idxOfCell = gNumbers.indexOf(chosenNum)
        if (gCells[idxOfCell].style.backgroundColor === 'red') {
            counter++
        }
        gNumbers.splice(idxOfCell, 1)
    }
}

function cellClicked(cell) {
    const numInsideCell = parseInt(cell.innerText)
    // const timestamp = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
    if (numInsideCell === chosenNum) {
        console.log('Awesome!')
        cell.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        playGame();
    } else {
        console.log('You tapped the wrong number.')
    }
}


function drawNum() {
    const idxOfEl = Math.floor(Math.random() * (gNumbers.length))
    return gNumbers[idxOfEl]
}


function addNumbers(numOfCells) {
    var randNum = 0
    var counter = 0
    while (counter < numOfCells) {
        randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (50 - 1) + 1)
        if (!gNumbers.includes(randNum)) {
            gNumbers.push(randNum)
            counter++
        } else continue
    }
}

// ------------

function userChoice() {
    var strHTML = ''
    strHTML += `
    <h1 style="text-align:center;margin:30px">Tap the numbers!</h1>
    <p>Please choose how many cells would you like to have:</p>
    <ul>
    <li onclick="displayBoard(this)">16</li>
    <li onclick="displayBoard(this)">25</li>
    <li onclick="displayBoard(this)">36</li>
    </ul>`
    gContainer.innerHTML = strHTML
}

function displayBoard(numOfCells) {
    chosenLength = parseInt(numOfCells.innerText)
    gTable.style.display = 'table'
    var chosenLength = parseInt(numOfCells.innerText)
    addNumbers(chosenLength)
    var counter = 0
    var strHTML = ''
    strHTML += `<tbody>`
    for (var i = 0; i < Math.sqrt(chosenLength); i++) {
        strHTML += `<tr>`
        for (var j = 0; j < Math.sqrt(chosenLength); j++) {
            strHTML += `<td data-location="${i}${j}" onclick="cellClicked(this)">${gNumbers[counter]}</td>`
            counter++
        }
        strHTML += `</tr>`
    }
    strHTML += `</tbody>`
    gTable.innerHTML = strHTML
    playGame()
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
<table></table>
```

Comment: I did it and it still does not work properly, I'm still getting undefined at the end :(